# Why signing an app for android with apache cordova fails?

Tags: cordova

I am using Apache Cordova that allows developers to create apps for various platforms. I created a keystore file in Android Studio and I entered this command in the CLI in order to produce a signed apk file that will be running in android devices:

```
cordova run android --release --keystore=../keystores-android/fd1.jks --storePassword=pass --alias=fd1 --password=pass
```

and I get a bunch of errors, which I don't understand and an unsigned apk file:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]

   Explanation for issues of type "MissingDefaultResource":
   If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
   and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values
   etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a device
   where the device is in a configuration missing the given qualifier.

   As a special case, drawables do not have to be specified in the base
   folder; if there is a match in a density folder (such as drawable-mdpi)
   that image will be used and scaled. Note however that if you  only specify
   a drawable in a folder like drawable-en-hdpi, the app will crash in
   non-English locales.

   There may be scenarios where you have a resource, such as a -fr drawable,
   which is only referenced from some other resource with the same qualifiers
   (such as a -fr style), which itself has safe fallbacks. However, this still
   makes it possible for somebody to accidentally reference the drawable and
   crash, so it is safer to create a default dummy fallback in the base
   folder. Alternatively, you can suppress the issue by adding
   tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource" on the element.

   (This scenario frequently happens with string translations, where you might
   delete code and the corresponding resources, but forget to delete a
   translation. There is a dedicated issue id for that scenario, with the id
   ExtraTranslation.)

12 errors, 0 warnings

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
43 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Deploying to emulator emulator-5554
Using apk: F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
Package name: com.fd.myteam.fd1
Command failed with exit code 1: adb -s emulator-5554 install -r F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
adb: failed to install F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl594732036.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]
Performing Streamed Install
```

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the drawable images. Try adding the splash to your `config.xml`

All of the failing/missing files are:

```
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
F:\2021-fd-local-server\fd1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
```

And you need to add the file and the splash config line into the `config.xml`

Add one line per each line that you have

```
<splash density="ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
```

Comment: Chux, where exactly do I put those lines, like <splash density="ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" /> in the config.xml?

Comment: into your src-cordovan/config.xml

<widget>
 <platform name="android">
    <!- Right here ->
 </platform>
</widget>

Comment: Thank you Chux. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Deprecated Gradle Warning : change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` in the **platforms/android/build.gradle** *dependencies* *classpath* (works with Gradle 6.5)